# YouTube api in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want my chrome extension to be able to get information about YouTube videos such as title, description and number of likes and use the YouTube api quota of the user for that. Can a chrome extension ask a user for permission to use his YouTube api?

If not, can a Chrome extension ask a user to enter his YouTube api key and make requests on behalf of the user?

Comment: This video doesn't answer any of my questions. Can a chrome extension ask a user for permission to use his YouTube api? Can a Chrome extension ask a user to enter his YouTube api key and make requests on behalf of the user?

Comment: An extension can automatically read the client's key from youtube site when it's shown in a tab. It's probably inside `yt` variable which you can read in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm I found `ytcfg.data_.INNERTUBE_API_KEY`, but it returns `PERMISSION_DENIED`. https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8&id=vXzp-ZofVl0&part=statistics

Comment: `ytcfg.data_.LINK_API_KEY` and `ytcfg.data_.VOZ_API_KEY` do not work either.